# winding number of $\gamma$ and point exterior to $\gamma$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, plane-curves

$$
\begin{align}
n(\gamma,z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z-z_0}dz .
\end{align}
$$

Is it safe to say that $n(\gamma,z)=0,\forall z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \gamma^*$

Comment: What is $\gamma^\ast$?

Comment: $\gamma^*$ is used in my textbook to describe the interior of a  closed curve .

Comment: And how is the interior defined if the closed curve is not a simple closed curve?

Comment: I don't think I know. All the cases so far have been simple closed curves. It's more like teacher's notes.

Comment: In the case you described how could we define the interior? Also , does the winding number make sense / exist if the curve isn't closed?

Comment: The curve must be closed for the winding number to make perfect sense, but it need not be  a _simple_ closed curve, it may intersect itself a number of times. One could then define the interior of the curve as the union of the bounded path components of the complement of the trace of the curve. Then you have $n(\gamma,z) = 0$ for all $z$ neither in the interior nor on the trace of the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not true.

However, $n(\gamma,z_0)=0$, for all $z_0$ in the (unique) unbounded connected component of $\mathbb C\smallsetminus \gamma$.

Comment: in the case that $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve ,is the unbounded connected component of $\mathbb{C} \ \gamma$ equal to  $\mathbb{C}\backslash \gamma^*$